# How retrieve nested table when using union

Tags: sql, oracle, union, nested-table

I'm trying to retrieve data from nested table in a sql view but when I want to add a union, oracle says  `inconsistent data type.`).

When I do :

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MY_VIEW
(
    VAR_1,
    VAR_2,
    VAR_3,
    VAR_4,
    VAR_5
)
    BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS
    SELECT 
           '0-0'            CHILD_ENTITY_ID,
           NULL             PARENT_ENTITY_ID,
           T2.LEVEL_ID      ENTITY_ID,
           NULL             PARENT_LEVEL_TYPE_ID,
          (SELECT ALERT_DAYS FROM TABLE(T6.ALERT_DAYS)) ALERT_DAYS
      FROM MA_TABLE_1    T1,
           MA_TABLE_2    T2,
           MA_TABLE_3    T3,
           MA_TABLE_4    T4,
           MA_TABLE_5    T5,
           MA_TABLE_6    T6,
           MA_TABLE_7    T7
     WHERE     T1.LEVEL_TYPE_ID = 0
           AND T1.LEVEL_TYPE_ID = T2.LEVEL_TYPE_ID
           AND T4.RATE_ID = T2.RATE_ID
           AND T4.COUNTER_DIVIDED_ID = T5.COUNTER_ID
           AND T2.ALERT_ID = T6.ALERT_ID(+)
           AND T2.RATE_ID = T7.RATE_ID
    UNION
    SELECT 
           '1-' || T2.OPERATOR_ID CHILD_ENTITY_ID,
           '0-0'                  PARENT_ENTITY_ID,
           T2.OPERATOR_ID         ENTITY_ID,
           0                      PARENT_LEVEL_TYPE_ID,
          (SELECT ALERT_DAYS FROM TABLE(T6.ALERT_DAYS)) ALERT_DAYS
      FROM MA_TABLE_3             T2,
           MA_TABLE_2             T3,
           MA_TABLE_4             T4,
           MA_TABLE_5             T5,
           MA_TABLE_6             T6,
           MA_TABLE_7             T7
     WHERE     ((T3.LEVEL_TYPE_ID = 1 AND T3.LEVEL_ID = T2.OPERATOR_ID))
           AND T3.LEVEL_TYPE_ID =
                   (SELECT MAX (T4.LEVEL_TYPE_ID)
                      FROM SMS_MONITORING_THRESHOLD T4
                     WHERE ((T4.LEVEL_TYPE_ID = 1
                           AND T4.LEVEL_ID = T2.OPERATOR_ID))
                           AND T4.RATE_ID = T3.RATE_ID
                           AND T3.CHANNEL_ID = T4.CHANNEL_ID)
           AND T4.RATE_ID = T3.RATE_ID
           AND T4.COUNTER_DIVIDED_ID = T5.COUNTER_ID
           AND T3.ALERT_ID = T6.ALERT_ID(+)
           AND T3.RATE_ID = T7.RATE_ID;
```

I'd got an error saying "wrong data types".

I've also tried to add to_char(...ALERT_DAYS) but without success.

I succeeded in avoiding error with this update :

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MY_VIEW
(
    VAR_1,
    VAR_2,
    VAR_3,
    VAR_4,
    VAR_5
)
    BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS
    SELECT 
           '0-0'            CHILD_ENTITY_ID,
           NULL             PARENT_ENTITY_ID,
           T2.LEVEL_ID      ENTITY_ID,
           NULL             PARENT_LEVEL_TYPE_ID,
          T8.*
      FROM MA_TABLE_1    T1,
           MA_TABLE_2    T2,
           MA_TABLE_3    T3,
           MA_TABLE_4    T4,
           MA_TABLE_5    T5,
           MA_TABLE_6    T6,
           MA_TABLE_7    T7,
           TABLE(T2.ALERT_DAYS) T8
     WHERE     T1.LEVEL_TYPE_ID = 0
           AND T1.LEVEL_TYPE_ID = T2.LEVEL_TYPE_ID
           AND T4.RATE_ID = T2.RATE_ID
           AND T4.COUNTER_DIVIDED_ID = T5.COUNTER_ID
           AND T2.ALERT_ID = T6.ALERT_ID(+)
           AND T2.RATE_ID = T7.RATE_ID
    UNION
    SELECT 
           '1-' || T2.OPERATOR_ID CHILD_ENTITY_ID,
           '0-0'                  PARENT_ENTITY_ID,
           T2.OPERATOR_ID         ENTITY_ID,
           0                      PARENT_LEVEL_TYPE_ID,
          T8.*
      FROM MA_TABLE_3             T2,
           MA_TABLE_2             T3,
           MA_TABLE_4             T4,
           MA_TABLE_5             T5,
           MA_TABLE_6             T6,
           MA_TABLE_7             T7,
           TABLE(T3.ALERT_DAYS) T8
     WHERE     ((T3.LEVEL_TYPE_ID = 1 AND T3.LEVEL_ID = T2.OPERATOR_ID))
           AND T3.LEVEL_TYPE_ID =
                   (SELECT MAX (T4.LEVEL_TYPE_ID)
                      FROM SMS_MONITORING_THRESHOLD T4
                     WHERE ((T4.LEVEL_TYPE_ID = 1
                           AND T4.LEVEL_ID = T2.OPERATOR_ID))
                           AND T4.RATE_ID = T3.RATE_ID
                           AND T3.CHANNEL_ID = T4.CHANNEL_ID)
           AND T4.RATE_ID = T3.RATE_ID
           AND T4.COUNTER_DIVIDED_ID = T5.COUNTER_ID
           AND T3.ALERT_ID = T6.ALERT_ID(+)
           AND T3.RATE_ID = T7.RATE_ID;
```

But now my view doesn't return anything and I don't understand why, if you have any idea, please let me know

Comment: Is this really the code?  because both selects appear to be identical so the data types can't be different.  Seems odd to union both tables; as the innate distinct would eliminate all the records from the union query (2nd)  it's like saying union (1,2) with (1,2) to get (1,2)... so why do the union... you're results wouldn't be (1,2),(1,2)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've updated my original post. Now it looks like more my real code

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MY_VIEW 
(
    ID,
    ALERT_DAYS
)
   BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS
    SELECT
         T1.ID,
         SELECT ALERT_DAYS FROM TABLE(to_number(T1.ALERT_DAYS)) ALERT_DAYS
    FROM 
        MA_TABLE T1
   UNION
    SELECT
         T1.ID,
         SELECT ALERT_DAYS FROM TABLE(to_number(T1.ALERT_DAYS)) ALERT_DAYS
    FROM 
        MA_TABLE T1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution but I've tried it and it doesn't work now the error says : 'inconsistent data type' expected NUMBER GOT MY_SCHEME.ALERT_DAYS_TAB

Comment: I've tried to use TO_NUMBER as your example but now the error is expected CHAR GOT MY_SCHEME.ALERT_DAYS_TAB, it's really weird

Comment: so try it with TO_CHAR